# Rails: Map of path helper methods to URL formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rake routes` gives me a mapping of "controllerName#method" to URL path format

`Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helpers` gives me a list of all helper methods.

Is there something that can give me a mapping of all helper methods to URL path formats? I'm not very experienced with Rails so something that tells me what URL the Rails helper methods actually generate would be EXTREMELEY awesome.

Comment: Just invoke the helper? It's a plain old method that returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused what you're asking? I think `rake routes` already tells you what you're looking for. Entries are in the format:

`route_name HTTP_VERB path controller#action`

Appending `_path` or `_url` to the `route_name` will give you a url helper. Ex. in my app I have

`scenario GET /scenarios/:id(.:format) scenarios#show`

And I can get a path or url to it by using `scenario_path(scenario)` or `scenario_url(scenario)` respectively.

Comment: You're right. My terminal window just wasn't big enough so I didn't see the helper method names.

Comment: So... this answers your question?